# WPF: Use element multiple times in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

For example I have an element in some XAML view.

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeName" Text="{Binding SomeText}"></TextBox>

<Grid>
    <!-- TODO: Render "SomeName" here-->
</Grid>
<Grid>
    <!-- TODO: Render "SomeName" here also-->
</Grid>
```

Is it possible?

For example by ContentControl or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about the ContentControl idea, you just need to use it with a "DataTemplate"

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeNameTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

<UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeText}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeNameTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeText}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeNameTemplate}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeText}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeNameTemplate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT:

The ContentControl and any control with a "Content" field can automatically select it's template by type.

```
// Let's define a collection item type
class Item
{
    public Item ( string text, DateTime date )
    {
        SomeText = text;
        SomeDate = date;
    }

    public string SomeText { get; private set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; private set; }
}

// A simple viewmodel
class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeViewModel ( )
    {
        Items.Add ( new Item ( "Item A", DateTime.MinValue ) );
        Items.Add ( new Item ( "Item B", DateTime.UtcNow   ) );
        Items.Add ( new Item ( "Item C", DateTime.MaxValue ) );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
     = new ObservableCollection<Item> ( );
}
```

Instead of giving it a key, we define our template by a type

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
            <DatePicker DisplayDate="{Binding SomeDate}" />
        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In both case, wpf will check the content's type and use our previous template we defined by type

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Items[0]}" />

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: ah, this is a variant, trying

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add another exemple of what you can do with the combo DataTemplate + ContentControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613(v=vs.100).aspx), as follows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="myTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="myText"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myTextBlock}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myTextBlock}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource myTextBlock}" Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, this is as a alternative solution. But what I ask about has no solution. I tried from code. It's not possible to render same element multiple times, It throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

as a possible solution you can define TextBox as non-shared resource. and then display that resource in different ContentControls (via Content property)

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Key="SomeName" Text="{Binding SomeText}" x:Shared="False"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SomeName}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SomeName}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

in this example **two** TextBoxes will be generated, both bound to SomeText